# Nested ifs versus serial logic bocks

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm trying to remove repetitive lines from my code.  Currently, it looks like this:

```
if (FALSE == DoFoo(strFile1, strData1))
{
    return (FALSE);
}
if (FALSE == DoFoo(strFile2, strData1))
{
    return (FALSE);
}
if (FALSE == DoFoo(strFile3, strData1))
{
    return (FALSE);
}
if (FALSE == DoBar(strData1))
{
    return (FALSE);
}
if (FALSE == DoFoo(strFile4, strData2))
{
    return (FALSE);
}
if (FALSE == DoFoo(strFile5, strData2))
{
    return (FALSE);
}
if (FALSE == DoFoo(strData1, strData2))
{
    return (FALSE);
}
if (FALSE == DoBar(strData2))
{
    return (FALSE);
}
return (TRUE);
```

I've changed it to look like this:

```
if (DoFoo(strFile1, strData1))
{
    if (DoFoo(strFile2, strData1))
    {
        if (DoFoo(strFile3, strData1))
        {
            if (DoBar(strData1))
            {
                if (DoFoo(strFile4, strData2))
                {
                    if (DoFoo(strFile5, strData2))
                    {
                        if (DoFoo(strData1, strData2))
                        {
                            if (DoBar(strData2))
                            {
                                return (TRUE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return (FALSE);
```

Is there a standard for nesting ifs?  Is there a generally agreed upon limit?  Normally, it could be confusing with so many nested, but since there is nothing complicated happening, no extra lines of code, it seems clear still. Which way is better?  Or is there another way to do this that would be neater and/or shorter than either of these?

Comment: Have you considered exceptions...

Comment: What is wrong with the original series?  It is quite readable and makes perfect sense.  The seriously indented if is more difficult to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a better way:

```
if(DoFoo(strFile1, strData1) && DoFoo(strFile2, strData1) && //etc...
    return true;
```

Or:

```
if(!DoFoo(strFile1, strData1) || !DoFoo(strFile2, strData1) || //etc...
    return false;
```

Comment: I wouldn't say &&, || would be better, yours would be saying if condition 1 and condition are true, return false where using || would say or, which is something it looks like he is aiming for.

Comment: @Sythnet I clarified it.

Answer (score 3):

I would implement it as follows:

```
bool func() {
  return DoFoo(strFile1, strData1)
     &&  DoFoo(strFile2, strData1)
     &&  DoFoo(strFile3, strData1)
     &&  DoBar(strData1)
     &&  DoFoo(strFile4, strData2)
     &&  DoFoo(strFile5, strData2)
     &&  DoFoo(strData1, strData2)
     &&  DoBar(strData2);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard for this. You are free to do what ever you want, until you work on the code alone.

But most people recommend to avoid it (limiting yourself by 1-2 nesting levels), because such a code is hard to read. The practise shows that in most cases this is possible.

In your case, for example, you can use && operator:

```
if ( DoFoo(strFile1, strData1) &&
     DoFoo(strFile2, strData1) &&
     DoFoo(strFile3, strData1) &&
     DoBar(strData1) &&
     DoFoo(strFile4, strData2) &&
     DoFoo(strFile5, strData2) &&
     DoFoo(strData1, strData2) &&
     DoBar(strData2)
   ) {
  return FALSE;
}
```

see? This is makes code much easier.

In other cases you can use

1. switch(...) operator.
2. Else if composition:

   ```
   if (A) {

   } else if (B) {

   } else if (C) {
   ...
   ```
3. Function calls:

   ```
   void CheckCoor( ... ) {
     if ( coor >= ... ) {
        CheckAngle(...);
     else {
        CheckPosibilityToChangeCoor(...);
     }
   }
   ```

Usually these 4 options is enough to avoid more than one nesting level.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like the following which is a different possibility that gets rid of nested if statements.

There is an ugly C like cast to make the table come out right and we assume that having additional, unused arguments will not be a problem.

This compiles and seems to work with Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 as a Windows console app when run in the debugger.  Of course the `DoFoo ()` and the `DoBar()` functions are both stubs in this example and the assumed char pointers do not point to anything but the structure is there.

```
bool DoFoo (char *s1, char *s2)
{
    return true;
}
bool DoBar (char *s1)
{
    return true;
}

char *strData1;
char *strData2;
char *strFile1;
char *strFile2;
char *strFile3;
char *strFile4;
char *strFile5;

typedef bool (*xFunc)(char *s1, char *s2);

typedef struct {
    xFunc  pF;
    char  *s1;
    char  *s2;
} TableItem;

bool myFunc(void)
{
TableItem fArray[] = {
    { DoFoo, strFile1, strData1},
    { DoFoo, strFile2, strData1},
    { DoFoo, strFile3, strData1},
    { (xFunc)DoBar, strData1, NULL},
    { DoFoo, strFile4, strData2},
    { DoFoo, strFile5, strData2},
    { DoFoo, strData1, strData2},
    { (xFunc)DoBar, strData2, NULL}
};

bool bRet = true;
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; bRet && i < sizeof(fArray)/sizeof(fArray[0]); i++) {
  bRet = fArray[i].pF(fArray[i].s1, fArray[i].s2) && bRet;
}

return bRet;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    myFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT - Another possibility**

Another way to do this would be as follows.  This does not require a C style cast.

```
bool DoFoo (char *s1, char *s2)
{
    return true;
}
bool DoBar (char *s1)
{
    return true;
}

char *strData1;
char *strData2;
char *strFile1;
char *strFile2;
char *strFile3;
char *strFile4;
char *strFile5;

typedef enum {funcType1 = 1, funcType2} funcType;

typedef struct {
    funcType fType;
    char     *s1;
    char     *s2;
} TableItem;

bool myFunc(void)
{
TableItem fArray[] = {
    { funcType1, strFile1, strData1},
    { funcType1, strFile2, strData1},
    { funcType1, strFile3, strData1},
    { funcType2, strData1, NULL},
    { funcType1, strFile4, strData2},
    { funcType1, strFile5, strData2},
    { funcType1, strData1, strData2},
    { funcType2, strData2, NULL}
};

bool bRet = true;
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; bRet && i < sizeof(fArray)/sizeof(fArray[0]); i++) {
    switch (fArray[i].fType) {
        case funcType1:
            bRet = DoFoo (fArray[i].s1, fArray[i].s2);
            break;
        case funcType2:
            bRet = DoBar (fArray[i].s1);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

return bRet;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    myFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT - Still Another possibility**

Another way to do this would be as follows.  This is pretty straight C++.

```
    bool DoFoo (char *s1, char *s2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    bool DoBar (char *s1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    char *strData1;
    char *strData2;
    char *strFile1;
    char *strFile2;
    char *strFile3;
    char *strFile4;
    char *strFile5;

class funcObj {
public:
    funcObj (bool (*pf) (char *s1, char *s2), char *s1, char *s2);
    funcObj (bool (*pf) (char *s1), char *s1);
    funcObj ();
    ~funcObj() {}
    bool eval ();
private:
    bool (*m_dofoo) (char *s1, char *s2);
    bool (*m_dobar) (char *s1);
    char  *m_s1;
    char  *m_s2;
};

funcObj::funcObj (bool (*pf) (char *s1, char *s2), char *s1, char *s2)
{
    m_dofoo = pf;
    m_dobar = 0;
    m_s1 = s1;
    m_s2 = s2;
}
funcObj::funcObj (bool (*pf) (char *s1), char *s1)
{
    m_dofoo = 0;
    m_dobar = pf;
    m_s1 = s1;
    m_s2 = 0;
}

funcObj::funcObj ()
{
    m_dofoo = 0;
    m_dobar = 0;
    m_s1 = 0;
    m_s2 = 0;
}

bool funcObj::eval ()
{
    bool bRet = false;

    if (m_dofoo)
        bRet = m_dofoo(m_s1, m_s2);
    else if (m_dobar)
        bRet = m_dobar (m_s1);
    return bRet;
}

typedef struct {
    funcObj  fObj;
} TableItem;

bool myFunc(void)
{
    funcObj fArray[] = {
        funcObj(DoFoo, strFile1, strData1),
        funcObj(DoFoo, strFile2, strData1),
        funcObj(DoFoo, strFile3, strData1),
        funcObj(DoBar, strData1),
        funcObj(DoFoo, strFile4, strData2),
        funcObj(DoFoo, strFile5, strData2),
        funcObj(DoFoo, strData1, strData2),
        funcObj(DoBar, strData2)
    };

    bool bRet = true;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; bRet && i < sizeof(fArray)/sizeof(fArray[0]); i++) {
        bRet = fArray[i].eval();
    }

    return bRet;
}
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        myFunc();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Really interesting idea, and that's a clever trick with `bRet` in the for condition.  But why include it in the assignment line?

Comment: @JoeMajsterski, that is a very good question and the answer is that I was so excited about the code that I did not do a final desk check!  You are right the bRet in the assignment is not needed.  Call it a brain hiccup.